# Backup Visual Studio Team Services Repository

Tags: version-control, azure-devops

I'm new to version control and am using Visual Studio Team Services and TFS. Is there a way to backup my repository before doing something like merging a branch? I'm just afraid that I could end up screwing something up in the original project and want to have a backup just in case.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an issue with a merge you can always roll back the changeset. If you want belt and braces, get the latest source into your workspace and then create a copy on your local file system.
When merging make sure you have the latest version of each branch before starting the merge.

Comment: Unless you use tf destroy, you can always get your source back at any point. Reference for rollback command line (also available in VS GUI): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd380776(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Git as your version control system you can always backup your local repository folder (it will be the exact copy of what exists on the server) or use `git reset` command to undo your latest changes.